# Deleting a js script

Tags: javascript

i installed a script that was meant to disable youtube scroll for details but it disabled scrolling over a different app. To use scroll in a different app i have to select it (click on it) and then scroll, otherwise it doesnt work. Heres what the js contains opened by notepad

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube - Disable Fullscreen Scroll
// @namespace    q1k
// @version      0.1
// @description  Disable scroll for details feature and remove the label from the bottom in fullscreen
// @author       q1k
// @match        https://*.youtube.com/*
// @match        http://*.youtube.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    if (document.body.classList.contains('no-scroll')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, { passive: false });

var css = document.createElement("style");
css.innerHTML=".ytp-fullerscreen-edu-button { display: none !important; }";
document.head.appendChild(css);
```

I have no idea what i was doing, can someone help me with disabling it?

Comment: You installed a userscript. So go to your userscript manager, find the script, and click “Disable”.

Comment: This probably belongs on Super User. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

As question is unclear I think you wrote this piece of code in your inspector window for that particular page. Which can be cleared by opening a new tab or new browser window , giving a fresh session which has original settings.